# Alamofire NSURLRequest Ambiguous use of URLString

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest, alamofire

So I'm relatively new to swift and recently I started a new project that required several network request to a JSON api on a remote server, so i decided to use Alamofire library (version 1.1 included via cocoapods) following these tutorials:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/87595/intermediate-alamofire-tutorial

Just in case it's relevant, here is the code i used in the podfile to include the Alamofire library:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.1'
```

One requirement was that images needed to be downloaded and cached for an specific tableview. Following the tutorials, i built an extension of the Alamofire.Request class the framework provides:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {

    class func imageResponseSerializer() -> Serializer {
        return { request, response, data in
            if data == nil {
                return (nil, nil)
            }

            let image = UIImage(data: data!, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

            return (image, nil)
        }
    }

    func responseImage(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(serializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: { (request, response, image, error) in
            completionHandler(request, response, image as? UIImage, error)
        })
    }

}
```

With this i requested images with

```
Alamofire.Request(.GET, "IMAGE URL").responseImage(){
     (request, _, image, error) in

     // Logic used to display image and save it to the cache

}
```

Testing the download without the cache shows that it works and i can display them, but the problem arises when i need the original URL as the key to my NSCache, but every time i try to access the property (request.URLString), xcode always throws a lot of errors.

Trying to access the property like this:

```
self.imageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: request.URLString)
```

throws "Ambiguous use of URLString" in the editor, and trying to compare it with other string values always throws an error saying "Cannot invoke 'operand' with an argument list of type '($T6??, String)'"

** Note that the number in $T6?? varies depending on where i'm using it

I tried searching for references to this kind of errors, but everything i found was related to how optionals work (don't know if that's the problem here, but none of them worked), so if anyone knows a solution to this error, i would really appreciate it.

**EDIT**

Here is the full function where i use it (commented in the lines where the errors appear)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Current Cell
        let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("entry_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as EntryTableViewCell

        // Current entry
        let entry = entries[indexPath.row]

        // Date Formatter
        var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle

        cell.entryTitle.text        = entry.title!
        cell.entryContent.text      = entry.content!
        cell.entryDateLabel.text    = formatter.stringFromDate(entry.createdAt!)

        // Try to download image
        let imageURL = ApplicationPreferences.resourcesURLPrefix + entry.picture!

        // 1
        if cell.request?.request.URLString != imageURL { // Error: cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '($T6??, String)'
            cell.request?.cancel()
        }

        // 2
        if let image = self.imageCache.objectForKey(imageURL) as? UIImage {
            cell.entryImageView.image = image
        } else {
            // 3
            cell.entryImageView.image = nil

            // 4
            cell.request = Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).responseImage() {
                (request, _, image, error) in

                if error == nil && image != nil {
                    // 5
                    self.imageCache.setObject(image!, forKey: request.URLString) // Error: Ambiguous use of 'URLString'

                    // 6
                    if request.URLString == cell.request?.request.URLString { // Error: Cannot invoke '==' with an argumet list of type '($T2??, $T8??)'
                        cell.entryImageView.image = image
                    }
                } else {
                    /*
                    If the cell went off-screen before the image was downloaded, we cancel it and
                    an NSURLErrorDomain (-999: cancelled) is returned. This is a normal behavior.
                    */
                }
            }
        }
        return cell

    }
```

Just in case, the source for that UITableViewCell subclass is:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class EntryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var entryImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var entryTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var entryContent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var entryDateBackgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var entryDateLabel: UILabel!

    var request: Alamofire.Request?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that `NSCache`/`NSMutableDictionary` syntax. I reproduced your extension and code snippet and it works fine for me (other than the `Alamofire.Request(.GET, ...)` syntax should be `Alamofire.request(.GET, ...)`). Often these cryptic `$T6`-style errors can crop up if there's something wrong earlier in the code (missing brace, etc.). But it's impossible to determine that on the basis of what's been provided thus far.

Comment: weird thing is that, everytime i try to access the URLString variable i get the "ambiguous use of URLString error", no matter where i use it in my code. Another thing is that this does not happens with the response.URL property (no idea why)

Comment: Well I just pulled Alamofire and tried it and it worked fine. First, there's the standard routine when you get unexplained behavior: (a) quit Xcode; (b) emptying derived data folder; (c) restart Xcode. If the problem persists, maybe upload reproducible example of the problem somewhere and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Again, I used your updated code sample and it compiled fine. Perhaps you can upload the project somewhere and we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Xcode 6.3b3...is that correct? If yes...read on. If not, please comment on this answer and I'll revise.

### Xcode 6.2

You have two places (number 1 and 6) where you are comparing a `URLString` against a `URLString?` which is why you are getting that compiler error. You'll need to optional bind above it or manually unwrap which probably isn't a good idea in either case.

Still not completely sure if number 5 has an actual problem or if it is a side affect of number 1 and 6.

### Xcode 6.3b3 and Swift 1.2

In the latest release of Swift, they tidied up some ambiguity in discerning which functions should be called when you have default parameter values. Alamofire has some invalid function calls that need to be refactored to work with the latest drop of the Swift 1.2 compiler. What you most likely need to do is to comment out the following lines in Alamofire.

```
public func response(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
    return response(Request.responseDataSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

This is one (there are a few) offender that is most likely tripping up your image serializer. I'll be pushing up a PR for this most likely tomorrow. I just thought in the meantime I'd point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I'm actually using Xcode 6.2 with the latest stable swift implementation (the one you get from the appstore), but still i tried commenting that function in the alamofire source code. I removed it from the Alamofire.swift file located in the Pods project, but still it's giving me the same error. I'm gonna post more code to see if it helps clarify the situation

Comment: Hi @EricDS, I updated my answer and I think I may have found your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, you are absolutely right on both points. I missed the change in his edit and for the first issue and the second one I was thinking he was accessing the `AnyObject?` return data. I'm going to pull the section that I added. Thanks for catching "my" mistakes.

Comment: You say "you are comparing a `URLString` against a `URLString?` which is why you are getting that compiler error". Really? Have you tried that? It works fine for me. Have you tried compiling this code?

Comment: as @Rob stated, that's not actually the issue here as NSURLRequest URLString property is of type String instead of String? (not an optional)

Comment: Yeah, but `cell.request?.request.URLString` is optional (via the optional chaining). But one can compare an optional to a non-optional without incident, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: Man then I'm out of suggestions gents without a sample project :(

Comment: At the end i ended up using cell.request?.request.URL.absoluteString! as the identifier, and the errors stopped